# Count the amount of balls that are same number

Tags: calculus, probability

I have two boxes A and B. The box A and the box B have same number of balls that are numbered from $1 ... n$. The balls in the box A are red balls and the box B are blue balls. All balls have same drawing probability. Randomly draw $k$ balls from the box A and $h$ balls from B. Find the expected number of balls from the drawing that have same number?

My solution may be
$$ \frac{\displaystyle\binom{n}{k}}{\displaystyle\binom{n}{h+k}}$$

Comment: An idea would be to consider the number of balls taken i.e starting with n balls choosen all will be the same.With n-1 balls chosen atleast n-2 and atmost n-1 would be the same.And so on until a pattern emerges.

Comment: Sorry, i did not catch the idea. Could you answer it  using final solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We assume the drawing is done without replacement. Without loss of generality we may assume that Balls $1$ to $k$ are drawn from Box A. For $i=1$ to $k$, let random variable $X_i$ be $1$ if ball $i$ is drawn from Box B, and $X_i=0$ otherwise.

Then the number $Y$ of "same numbers" is given by $Y=X_1+\cdots+X_k$. 
By the linearity of expectation we have $E(Y)=E(X_1)+\cdots+E(X_k)$.

Note that for any $i$, we have $E(X_i)=\Pr(X_i=1)=\frac{h}{n}$. Adding up, we get $E(Y)=\frac{kh}{n}$.

*Another way:* The following indicator random variable argument is nicer, since it is more symmetric. For $i=1$ to $n$, let $W_i=1$ if ball $i$ is drawn from *both* boxes, and $W_i=0$ otherwise. Then $Y=W_1+\cdots +W_n$. Note that $\Pr(W_i=1)=\frac{k}{n}\cdot \frac{h}{n}$. Thus the usual linearity of expectation argument shows that $E(Y)=n\cdot \frac{hk}{n^2}=\frac{hk}{n}$.

Comment: I totally agree with your solution. If $n=3,k=2,h=1$ then E[Y]=2/3. Does it make scene?thanks

Comment: @markjohn: Yes, that is correct. For the small numbers you mention, we can explicitly find $\Pr(Y=0)$ and $\Pr(Y=1)$. And now that we know the distribution of $Y$, we can compute $E(Y)$ in the obvious way. For the general situation, we can find *expressions* for the probability that $Y=y$, and in principle then write down an expression for the expectation. This expression will turn out to simplify greatly to $\frac{hk}{n}$. I have not checked whether this cumbersome approach can be pushed through with any ease. Hence the Method of Indicator Random Variables to the rescue!

Comment: If you do not yet have the Method yet as a tool, then maybe (shudder!) you will have to go for the distribution of $Y$. A lot of binomial coefficients.

Comment: Thank Andre Nicolas. Could you help me to solve the problem in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1888295/how-to-find-expected-solved-variables-from-a-linear-equation