# How to find expected solved variables from a linear equation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I have a difficult problem about probability that needs your help. Let $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ be four unknown variables. From these variables, we can created a set of equations as follows:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        x_1 &     &     &    \\
            & x_2 &     &    \\
            &     & x_3 &    \\
            &     &     & x_4\\
        x_1 +x_2&    &     &    \\
        x_1+ x_3&    &     &    \\
        x_1+ x_4&    &     &    \\
                & x_2 +x_3    &     & \\
       \vdots\\
       x_1 +x_2+x_3&     &     & \\
       x_1 +x_2+x_4&     &     & \\
                   &x_2 +x_3+x_4     &     & \\
       \vdots\\
       x_1 +x_2+x_3+x_4&     &     & \\
        \end{pmatrix}
    =   \begin{pmatrix}
        d_1\\
        d_2\\
        d_3\\ 
        d_4\\
        d_5\\
        d_6\\
        d_7\\
        d_8\\
        \vdots\\
        d_9\\
        d_{10}\\
        d_{11}\\
        \vdots\\
        d_{12}\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

The left side of the equation is created by four groups: the first group is created from a single variable, the second groups is a combination of two variables, the third groups is a combination of three variables and so on. The right side is a known vector $d$.

In the first phase, I will randomly pick $n_1$ equations from group 1, **without replacement** (each equation is chosen one time). The second phase, I randomly pick $n_2$ equations **with replacement** (means some equation can chosen more than one time) from all groups: 1 to 4, the probability of choosing group follows the rule:

$P(Group1)=0.2;P(Group2)=0.5;P(Group3)=0.2;P(Group4)=0.1;$

These $n_1+n_2$ selected equation give us a new linear equation. My question is how to find the expected solved variables can we have from  the $n_1+n_2$ linear equation?